# Weighted shift operator is Hilbert-Schmidt

Tags: operator-theory, compactness

If $W : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ is the weighted shift operator defined by $$W(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(0,x_1,\frac 12x_2,\frac 13x_3,\ldots),$$ how can I show that $W$ is Hilbert-Schmidt?

If I have $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ as the orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$, then I need to show that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \|We_j\|^2 < \infty$.

So far, I have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \|We_n\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left( \frac 1j e_{jn} \right)^2.$$
If this is correct so far, what can I do next?

Comment: I rolled back to the previous version, because this is closer to the version that Silvia answered. IMO other users who helped you are entitled to this much protection. Nevertheless, congrats for figuring it out in the end! Glad to see that you posted an answer. That way you can get even more feedback in case you missed some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $$W(e_n)=W(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-1 \text{ terms}},1,0,\ldots)=(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n \text{ terms}},\frac 1n,0,\ldots)$$ so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|We_n\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} < \infty.$$

Answer (score 7):

You are done, just need to clarify your notation.

You have $\|W\|_{HS}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|We_n\|^2= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2} < \infty$.